# Long list of SQL parameters and audits

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Say I have the following code. What are your thoughts on questions 1-4 below?

1. I think it's way too long when I have to list out most of the fields. Is there any better way of doing this?
2. I build up the DB column name so it can be used later in my select and insert statement.
3. This is where and how I use the string I build up in Section 2. Does it look good or ugly?
4. Audit is required after inserting/update a new record, therefore I need to get the old and new value. There should be a better way to do this I guess, but I just have no idea how.

I'm open to any suggestion that can make this code block short and more readable.

```
Public Function InsertOrUpdateData(ByVal patient As Patient, ByVal sqlMode As SQLMode, ByVal affectedColumn As String, Optional ByVal updateString As String = "") As CreatePatientStatus
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(_myConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = conn
        conn.Open()
        Try
            'SECTION 1
            'first I populate all the param before perform any action
            With cmd.Parameters
                .AddWithValue("@PCNO", patient.PCNO)
                .AddWithValue("@PName", patient.PName)
                .AddWithValue("@NRICType", patient.NRICType)
                .AddWithValue("@NRIC", patient.NRIC)
                'Another 80+ fields
                .AddWithValue("@Created_Date", Now)
                .AddWithValue("@Created_By", patient.CreateOrEditBy)
                .AddWithValue("@Edit_Date", Now)
                .AddWithValue("@Edit_By", patient.CreateOrEditBy)
                .AddWithValue("@FirstSeen", Now)
            End With

            'SECTION 2
            'this is list out all the affected DB column (It's FIXED, and always be)
            Dim sbAffectedDBFields As New StringBuilder
            sbAffectedDBFields.Append("PCNO,PName,NRICType,NRIC,")
            sbAffectedDBFields.Append("Anoter 80+ fields")
            sbAffectedDBFields.Append("Created_Date,Created_By,Edit_Date,Edit_By,FirstSeen")

            'oldValue and newValue to be used later part for audit
            Dim oldValue As String = String.Empty
            Dim newValue As String = String.Empty
            Dim dtOldValue As New DataTable
            Dim dtNewValue As New DataTable
            Dim sqlDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

            If sqlMode = sqlMode.INSERT Then
                'insert patient
                'SECTION 3
                cmd.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO myPatient({0}) VALUES ({1})", sbAffectedDBFields.ToString, sbAffectedDBFields.Replace(",", ",@").ToString)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            ElseIf sqlMode = sqlMode.UPDATE Then
                'get old value before update
                cmd.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT {0} FROM myPatient WHERE PCNO=@PCNO", sbAffectedDBFields.ToString)
                sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PCNO", patient.PCNO)
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dtOldValue)

                'dtOldValue will have only one row always
                'SECTION 4
                For Each dr As DataRow In dtOldValue.Rows
                    For Each dc As DataColumn In dtOldValue.Columns
                        oldValue &= dr(dc).ToString & ","
                    Next
                Next
                oldValue.Remove(oldValue.Length - 1, 1) 'to remove last ","

                'update patient
                'updateString variable in a format of (field1=@field1,field2=@field2,fieldN=@fieldN)
                cmd.CommandText = String.Format("UPDATE myPatient SET {0} WHERE PCNO=@PCNO", updateString)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If

            'get new value after update
            cmd.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT {0} FROM myPatient WHERE PCNO=@PCNO", sbAffectedDBFields.ToString)
            sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PCNO", patient.PCNO)
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dtNewValue)

            'dtNewValue will have only one row always
            For Each dr As DataRow In dtNewValue.Rows
                For Each dc As DataColumn In dtNewValue.Columns
                    newValue &= dr(dc).ToString & ","
                Next
            Next
            newValue.Remove(newValue.Length - 1, 1) 'to remove last ","

            'param tableName,affectedColumn,oldvalue,newvalue
            Audit("myPatient", sbAffectedDBFields.ToString, oldValue, newValue)

            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorLog.Log(ex, ErrorLog.LogLevel.Message, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod())
            Return False
        End Try
    End Using
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **I think it's way too long when I have to list out most of the fields. Is there any better way of doing this?**

Extract the creation of the parameters in a method passing in the `Patient` object and the  `SqlParameterCollection` of the `SqlCommand` object

```
Private Sub FillPatientParameterCollection(patient As Patient, parameters As SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection)

    Dim currentDate As Date = Now

    With parameters
        .AddWithValue("@PCNO", patient.PCNO)
        .AddWithValue("@PName", patient.PName)
        .AddWithValue("@NRICType", patient.NRICType)
        .AddWithValue("@NRIC", patient.NRIC)
        'Another 80+ fields
        .AddWithValue("@Created_Date", currentDate)
        .AddWithValue("@Created_By", patient.CreateOrEditBy)
        .AddWithValue("@Edit_Date", currentDate)
        .AddWithValue("@Edit_By", patient.CreateOrEditBy)
        .AddWithValue("@FirstSeen", currentDate)
    End With

End Sub
```

Also see the `currentDate`variable. This ensures that the values for Created_Date,Edit_Date... are the same.

call the method like

```
FillPatientParameterCollection (patient, cmd.Parameters)
```

> **I build up the DB column name so it can be used later in my select and insert statement.**

This should also be extracted in a own method but made accessible by a property. In this way it needs to be filled only once. This method should return a `List(Of String)` as this is easier to read and to maintain.

```
Private _AffectedDBFields As List(Of String)
Private ReadOnly Property AffectedDBFields As List(Of String)
    Get
        If (_AffectedDBFields.Count = 0) Then
            _AffectedDBFields = GetAffectedDBFields()
        End If
        Return _AffectedDBFields
    End Get
End Property
Private Function GetAffectedDBFields() As List(Of String)
    Dim affectedFields As New List(Of String)()
    affectedFields.Add("PCNO")
    affectedFields.Add("PName")
    affectedFields.Add("NRICType")
    affectedFields.Add("NRIC")
    affectedFields.Add("Anoter 80+ fields")
    affectedFields.Add("Created_Date")
    Return affectedFields
End Function
```

> **This is where and how I use the string I build up in Section 2. Does it look good or ugly?**

As you don't have a `StringBuilder`object anymore you need to use the [String.Join()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

So this

```
cmd.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO myPatient({0}) VALUES ({1})", sbAffectedDBFields.ToString, sbAffectedDBFields.Replace(",", ",@").ToString)
```

will become this

```
cmd.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO myPatient({0}) VALUES ({1})", String.Join(",", AffectedDBFields), String.Join(",@", AffectedDBFields))
```

> **Audit is required after inserting/update a new record, therefore I need to get the old and new value. There should be a better way to do this I guess, but I just have no idea how.**

You should extract the loop over the dtOldValues.Rows and also dtNewValues.Rows to a method, which again can return a List(Of String) instead of a `String`

```
Private Function GetDataRowValues(row As DataRow) As List(Of String)
    Dim values As New List(Of String)()
    For Each dc As DataColumn In row.Table.Columns
        Dim value As String = String.Empty
        If (Not IsDBNull(row(dc))) Then
            value = row(dc).ToString()
        End If
        values.Add(value)
    Next
    Return values
End Function
```

You then call this method with a guard condition like this

```
If dtOldValue.Rows.Count > 0 then
    oldValue = String.Join(",",GetDataRowValues(dtOldValues.Rows(0)))
End If
```

and

```
If dtNewValue.Rows.Count > 0 then
    newValue = String.Join(",",GetDataRowValues(dtNewValues.Rows(0)))
End If
```

At the end you need to call your Audit() like

```
Audit("myPatient", String.Join(",", AffectedDBFields), oldValue, newValue)
```

### Additional remarks

I have integrated a check for DbNull values in the GetDataRowValues() method. You should always check for DbNull values.